# Extract hashtags after scraping tweets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, twitter

I have scraped the tweets. Within entities there are hashtags. The hashtags values are within label text as nested dictionary. I am trying to extract the hashtags for each tweet in python.

It will be helpful if I can get guidance on getting the hashtags

```
df['entities']
```

output =>

```
0  {'hashtags': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1460865425911205891', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [117, 140]}]}
1  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'carbon', 'indices': [17, 24]}, {'text': 'nature', 'indices': [48, 55]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://rpujolviven.blogspot.com/2012/10/infinite-growth.html', 'display_url': 'rpujolviven.blogspot.com/2012/10/infini…', 'indices': [61, 84]}, {'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https...
2  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Lincoln', 'indices': [69, 77]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': '', 'expanded_url': 'https://thelincolnite.co.uk/2021/11/professor-duncan-french-the-juggernaut-of-climate-politics-rolls-on/', 'display_url': 'thelincolnite.co.uk/2021/11/profes…', 'indices': [78, 101]}]}
3  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'CBDC', 'indices': [107, 112]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [{'url': , 'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1460865388699344900', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…', 'indices': [115, 138]}]}
```

The expected output:

```
 0  []
 1  ['carbon', 'nature']
 2  ['Lincoln']
 3  ['CBDC']
```

Comment: @BigBen thanx for the response. I have added a sample dataframe for understanding